# What does the letter+number on the GOMTV GSL scoreboard mean?

Tags: starcraft-2

[image: GOMTV GSL Scoreboard]

On the above picture of a GOMTV GSL scoreboard I assume the P and T stand for Protoss and Terran, but what does the number mean?  Seed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is their relative location on the minimap, by using the numbers on the face of an analog clock. P3 means the Protoss's main (original) base is towards the right middle, and T9 means the Terran's main is towards the left middle of the minimap.